# Nextgen gallery image upload to a blob storage in windows azure

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery, azure-blob-storage

I am fairly new to php development in WordPress.

I am using Next-gen gallery plugin. Its a nice plugin but I am facing difficulty in finding a way to upload images to the blob storage in windows azure.

Currently the storage space is an issue as there are alot of images in the gallery and it effects the web server performance in keeping the images in web server.

Windows azure blob storage plugin is activated on the wordpress website and all the images in the media gallery are uploaded into the blob.

The nextgen gallery media library addon is also activated but when I try to add image from media library into nextgen gallery, It copies the image into the wp-content/gallery/{gallery name} on the webserver.

Search on the internet has not brought any satisfying answers to me. May be some one out there has some brilliant solution to this.

I am using WordPress 3.8.1 on windows azure.